# Filter twitter files by location

Tags: python, json, twitter, dictionary, key

I am trying to find lat/long information for numerous tweets.  One path to a tweet lat/long data in a json tweet is,

{u'location: {u'geo': {u'coordinates : [120.0,-5.0]}}}

I want to be able to check each tweet if this location path exists.  If it does then I want to use that information in a function later on.  If it does not then I want to check another location path and finally move on to the next tweet.

Here is the code I have currently to check if this path exists and if there is corresponding data.  'data' is a list of twitter files that I opened using the *data.append(json.loads(line))* method.

```
counter = 0
for line in data:
    if u'coordinates' in data[counter][u'location'][u'geo']:

        print counter, "HAS FIELD"
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter += 1
        print counter, 'no location data'
```

I get a KeyError error with this code.  If I just do the below code it works, but is not specific enough to actually get me to the information that I need.

```
counter = 0
for line in data:
    if u'location' in data[counter]:

        print counter, "HAS FIELD"
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter += 1
        print counter, 'no location data'
```

Does anyone have a way to do this.

Below is some more background on what I am doing overall, but the above sums up where I am stuck.

Background:  I have access to 12 billion tweets, purchased through gnip, that are divided up into multiple files.  I am trying to comb through those tweets one-by-one and find which ones have location (lat/long) data and then see if the corresponding coordinates fall in a certain country.  If that tweet does fall in that country I will add it to a new database which is a subset of the my larger database.

I have successfully created a function to test if a lat/long falls in the bounding box of my target country, but I am having difficulty populating the lat/long for each tweet for 2 reasons.  1)  There are multiple places that long/lat data are stored in each json file, if it exists at all.  2)  The tweets are organized in a complex dictionary of dictionaries which I have difficulty maneuvering through.

I need to be able to loop through each tweet and see if a specific lat/long combination exists for the different location paths so that I can pull it and feed it into my function that tests if that tweet originated in my country of interest.

Answer (score 0):

> I get a KeyError error with this code

Assume keys should be in double quotes because they have `'`:

```
counter = 0
for line in data:
    if "u'coordinates" in data[counter]["u'location"]["u'geo"]:

        print counter, "HAS FIELD"
        counter += 1
    else:
        counter += 1
        print counter, 'no location data'
```

Comment: I checked it, but it didn't seem to work.  The actual key is 'coordinates'.  When I read the file in it becomes u'coordinates' because it is Unicode.  In my second example, I use the key u'location', which is a top layer key in data[counter] and it works fine.  It seems that I cannot call on a sub layer dictionary key.  Maybe it is not strictly considered a key?  I have experimented with try-except, which seems to work because it allows me to push through KeyError errors , but I don't know if it is working like an if-else statement, which seems the best way to check multiple  location paths.

Comment: I checked the following path: _u'coordinates' in data[counter][u'location'][u'geo']_ and I get a True statement, but it only works if the key exists in that specific tweet.  For tweets that don't have that path, I do not get a False statement but instead I get a KeyError.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found may not be the most efficient, but is functional.  It uses *if* statements nested in *try-except* statements.  This allows me to check different location paths but push through *KeyError* s so that I can move on to other tweets and pathways.  Below is my code.  It goes through multiple tweets and checks for ones that have an available Lat/Long combos in any of 3 pathways.  It works with my *addTOdb* function that checks to see if that Lat/Long combo is in my target country.  It also builds a separate dictionary called *Lat Long* where I can view all the tweets that had Lat/Long combos and what path I pulled them through.

```html
#use try/except function to see if entry is in json files
#initialize counter that numbers each json entry
counter = 0
#This is a test dict to see what lat long was selected
Lat_Long = {}
for line in data:
    TweetLat = 0
    TweetLong = 0
    #variable that will indicate what path was used for coordinate lat/long
    CoordSource = 0
    #Sets while variable to False.  Will change if coords are found.
    GotCoord = False
    while GotCoord == False:
        #check 1st path using geo function
        try:
            
            if u'coordinates' in data[counter][u'geo'] and GotCoord == False:
                TweetLat = data[counter][u'geo'][u'coordinates'][0]
                TweetLong = data[counter][u'geo'][u'coordinates'][1]
                #print 'TweetLat',TweetLat
                print counter, "HAS FIELD"
                addTOdb(TweetLat,TweetLong,North,South,East,West)
                CoordSource = 1
                GotCoord = True
        except KeyError:
            pass
        #check 2nd path using gnip info
        try:
            if u'coordinates' in data[counter][u'gnip'][u'profileLocations'][0][u'geo'] and GotCoord == False:
                TweetLat = data[counter][u'gnip'][u'profileLocations'][0][u'geo'][u'coordinates'][1]
                TweetLong = data[counter][u'gnip'][u'profileLocations'][0][u'geo'][u'coordinates'][0]
                print counter, "HAS FIELD"
                addTOdb(TweetLat,TweetLong,North,South,East,West)
                CoordSource = 2
                GotCoord = True
        except KeyError:
            pass
        #check 3rd path using location polygon info
        try:     
            if u'coordinates' in data[counter][u'location'][u'geo'] and GotCoord == False:
                TweetLat = data[counter][u'location'][u'geo'][u'coordinates'][0][0][1]
                TweetLong = data[counter][u'location'][u'geo'][u'coordinates'][0][0][0]
                print counter, "HAS FIELD"
                addTOdb(TweetLat,TweetLong,North,South,East,West)
                CoordSource = 3
                GotCoord = True
        except KeyError:
            pass
         
        if GotCoord==True:
            Lat_Long[counter] = [CoordSource,TweetLat, TweetLong]
        else:
            print counter, "no field"
            GotCoord = True       
    counter += 1
```